# How to add Context class within another class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use Localbroadcast to send latitude and longitude over to the main activity. But the parameter of `this` within `getInstance()` isn't working. I tried adding the context class but it is still wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
companion object {
    val TAG = "LocationTrackingService"

    val INTERVAL = 5000.toLong() // In milliseconds
    val DISTANCE = 0.toFloat() // In meters

    val locationListeners = arrayOf(
        LTRLocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        LTRLocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    )
    private fun sendRequest() {
        // The string "GPS_not_activaded" will be used to filer the intent
        val intentRequest = Intent("Sending_location_coordinates")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentRequest)
        Log.d(TAG,"Se enviaron las coordenadas")
    }

    class LTRLocationListener(provider: String) : android.location.LocationListener {

        val lastLocation = Location(provider)


        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
            lastLocation.set(location)
            Log.d(TAG, "======================= New Data =======================")
            Log.d(TAG,"latitud: "+ lastLocation.latitude)
            Log.d(TAG,"longitud: "+ lastLocation.longitude)
            sendRequest()
        }
```

Comment: why are you nesting all of this in a companion object? `this` refers to the Companion itself, which is not a subclass of Context

Comment: I nested the companion for extra variables for the service, I don't understand really well the context, should i put all of the data outside the companion?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 this@LocationTrackingService
```

to get `LocationTrackingService` class `this` object.

More about `this` object [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html).

Comment: I tried doing this but no result :( Any other ideas?